# How to discard pages from PDF output without affecting text color

Tags: color, pagesel

I need to output only 1 specific page from LaTeX document for which I use the `pagesel` package; the text itself has `\color` set which is discarded along with the first page.

The whole text, both pages, looks and renders like this (note the greyish text color, using LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
% \usepackage[2]{pagesel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color[cmyk]{.2,.2,.2,.4}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: 2 pages rendered]

while when I uncomment the `\usepackage[2]{pagesel}` line, I get this:
[image: 1 page rendered]

I need to solve this from within LaTeX, as the document is embedded in Scribus as LaTeX render frame; getting pages from PDF via command-line utilities is easy but not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using lualatex you could try the luacolor package. It implements colors using attributes and they are not lost when you remove pages:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[2]{pagesel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\begin{document}

\color{red}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a "best practice" to always load luacolor when using LuaLaTeX and using colors?

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker It is certainly more powerful than the standard color packages (e.g. it has no problems with different colors in footnotes and text). But I'm normally not using it as it doesn't work with other engines. So I don't know if it has e.g. hidden bugs.